# Apache2 random 403 error & info server busy logs on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a strange situation with apache2. Meanless, random 403 errors. Any page (html, php etc.) normally working. but if i request repeatedly by pressing refresh button of browser. it interrupts & sends a 403 randomly. after a few seconds it works again. 
in the error log, i see `client denied by server configuration`. 
main error log of apache says 
`[info] server seems busy, (you may need to increase StartServers, or Min/MaxSpareServers), spawning 8 children, there are 99 idle, and 137 total children`
my current values
`IfModule mpm_prefork_module
StartServers 120
MinSpareServers 100
MaxSpareServers 200
MaxClients          256
MaxRequestsPerChild 500
/IfModule`

i've increased 10 by 10. from 20. but nothing solved.  i've disabled KeepAlive.

What may cause this problem ?
thank you in advance.

---

a fresh install Ubuntu server x86 8.04.4 
Virtualmin from it's website (not from debian repositories). 
Linux 2.6.24-27-server #1 SMP i686 - Apache 2.2.8 Mpm prefork
Virtualmin version 3.78.gpl GPL 
PHP Version 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10
Loaded modules: 
core_module (static)  log_config_module (static)  logio_module (static)  mpm_prefork_module (static)  http_module (static)  so_module (static) actions_module shared) alias_module (shared) auth_basic_module (shared) auth_digest_module (shared) uthn_file_module (shared) authz_default_module (shared) authz_groupfile_module (shared) uthz_host_module (shared) authz_user_module (shared) autoindex_module (shared) ache_module shared) cgi_module (shared) deflate_module (shared) dir_module (shared) env_module (shared) expires_module (shared) fcgid_module (shared) file_cache_module (shared) eaders_module (shared) mime_module (shared) mime_magic_module (shared) evasive20_module shared) negotiation_module (shared) php5_module (shared) rewrite_module (shared) etenvif_module (shared) ssl_module (shared) status_module (shared) 
Syntax OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was mod_evasive.
http dos & ddos protection module.

i couldn't think it may log as "server busy". 
also mod_evasive itself is not dropping any log.

any fast solution seeker like me can misunderstand the situation.

thank you again.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. The default settings of mod_evasive are ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server under heavy load?
Maybe try to enable mod_status and see what happen when you get 403.

Comment: there is no heavy load. i've checked many times with mod_status.  but no luck.